# How to find closed loop more efficiently

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

I have the following data structures and algorithms question that I've been trying to think a better solution for -

Given

$x is longitude and
$y is latitude

and the following characters

'>' east  $x++ ;
'<' west  $x-- ;
'^' north $y++ ;
'v' south $y-- ;

and the sample input as a string
"^V<>><^>v<>^<^>^>>v>><^^<>><<<><<><^<^v<^^v<<>><<<<^>v^>v^v^<<>>v<><^<>><>>^><>v^v>v<<>v<>v^^><<>>>v<<>>>>^>v>>”

write a function that identifies all closed loops (some samples given below are examples of closed loop)
[
    “^v”,
    “<>”,
    “><“,
    “^>v<“,
    ...
]

I have been able to solve this in O(n^2) by picking each character from the input given and then going through the entire string and keeping two count variables - one for vertical count and another for horizontal count, at any point the value on both is zero then it's a closed loop. But I am wondering if there is someone who can do this more efficiently - maybe there's some algorithm I am missing out.

Thanks & Regards,
Vaibhav

Comment: Hint: Don't think of it as "searching for substrings". Think of it as "recognizing when you've returned to a place you were before". Any time you do that, you've looped.

Comment: Any restrictions on the space used? With O(n) space you can do it in O(n) time.

Comment: @Sneftel - yes! this is why I am maintaining those two count variables. But this checking of when I've returned to the same place is an O(n) operation right and I have to do it for each character, making it O(n^2)

Comment: @Henry - no restrictions on space. Can you explain?

Comment: Note that we have to find all closed loops in this given string

Comment: @KumarVaibhav It doesn't have to be O(n). "Have you ever been at location `[3,5]` before" is a trivial operation to answer in O(1). Just use a 2D table, containing the last time you were at a particular spot.

Comment: BTW, think about how to handle compound loops. There's a couple of approaches, but they both require thinking about.

Comment: Oh, and I wouldn't use a hash if I were you. Needless complexity if you have unbounded space.

Comment: Initializing a 2D table takes O(n^2) time, assuming that the max entents in each dimension scale linearly with n

Comment: @samgak It does not, since you can make a pre-run along the path and only initialize the O(n) cells which you will visit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a bitset of arbitrary length, e.g. n.

Define a hashing function that maps a pair of x,y co-ordinates to a bit in the bitset.

Start at the beginning of the string, initializing the current x and y to zero.

For each character, compute the hash and check the corresponding bit in the bitset. If if is set then check if there is a loop ending at the current character, using your current algorithm, working backwards. Then set the bit for the current position, adjust x and y based on the character and move onto the next character.

The bitset serves as a quick check to see whether a loop is possible ending at the current character, with a full check done only in the case the bit is set, to avoid false positives in the case of hash collisions, and also find the starting character of the loop. It also allows you to handle more complex loops that return to the same position more than once (such as a figure 8 loop that begins and ends at the cross), if you want to count them separately to the smaller loops they contain.

Comment: Seems like the solution I was looking for. Sneftel was right in saying I was thinking in terms of finding a substring rather than thinking about it as a 2D plot. Thanks @Sneftel  !

Answer (score 1):

i'd suggest smth around the following:

```
Map (X,Y) => N  as  visited;

for(int i=0; i<input_str.length; ++i){
    ! update (x,y) per input_str[i];

    if(visited.has(x,y))
    {
        last_visit_index = visited[x,y];
        loop = input_str.substring   last_visit_index to i
    }
    visited[x,y] = i;
}
```

this is `O(N)`.

Comment: Isn't substring at least O (n) ?

Comment: @Kumar not at all... it can be O(1). take cpp `str[start+len]='\0'; return &str[start]` even though this impl destroies the original string.